# Apache2.4 ignores my logfiledir setting

Tags: apache-2.4, log-files

I extended `config.layout` with my own layout which is used to build Apache 2.4.23.

For some reasons the directory specified under `logfiledir` is ignored. I was testing the other directory entries [for example `datadir`] and these settings work [e.q. the directories are created by `make install` and the files are copied into these directories].

**My question:**

What am I doing wrong; how can I set the path for the log file to `/var/log/apache2`?

**The very strange thing is that `make install` is creating the directory `/var/log/apache2` but the log files are written to `/FaF/logs`!**

**Info:**

Linux: SLES 12 SP1

Run: `./configure --enable-layout=FaF ....`

Definition of the layout `FaF` in `config.layout`:

```
<Layout FaF>
    prefix:        /FaF
    exec_prefix:   ${prefix}
    bindir:        ${prefix}/bin
    sbindir:       ${prefix}/sbin
    libdir:        ${prefix}/lib
    libexecdir:    ${prefix}/lib/apache
    mandir:        ${prefix}/share/man
    sysconfdir:    /etc/apache2
    datadir:       /usr/local/apache2
    installbuilddir: ${datadir}/build
    errordir:      ${datadir}/error
    iconsdir:      ${datadir}/icons
    htdocsdir:     ${datadir}/htdocs
    manualdir:     ${datadir}/manual
    cgidir:        ${datadir}/cgi-bin
    includedir:    ${prefix}/include/apache
    localstatedir: /var/lib/apache2
    runtimedir:    /var/run
    logfiledir:    /var/log/apache2    <-- 
    proxycachedir: /var/cache/apache2
</Layout>
```

Comment: I would prefer not to rely on build time options but would rather explicitly configure Apache  using the ErrorLog directive in it's configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two reasons:**

1. Due to intensiv testing the configuration got *dirty* and regardless what I entered the settings provided the first time were kept. Solution: Delete the whole `build` directory, extract it from the archive and run `configure` again. This solved almost every issue.
2. @HBruijn confirmed what I realized: Do not count on some `...dir` values provided to `configure` - set them in the configuration file.

Following the above 2 points now it works as expected.